# Remove part of link from each href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove from each link in the page part of the link

The current link like this

```
http://domain.com/download.php?url=https://www.dropbox.com/file1.rar
```

I need the link to be like this

```
https://www.dropbox.com/file1.rar
```

So just remove this `http://domain.com/download.php?url=`

This Is my code

```
<a href="http://domain.com/download.php?url=https://www.dropbox.com/file1.rar">Download File 1</a><br>
<a href="http://domain.com/download.php?url=https://www.dropbox.com/file2.rar">Download File 2</a><br>
<a href="http://domain.com/download.php?url=https://www.dropbox.com/file3.rar">Download File 3</a><br>
<a href="http://domain.com/download.php?url=https://www.dropbox.com/file4.rar">Download File 4</a><br>
<a href="http://domain.com/download.php?url=https://www.dropbox.com/file5.rar">Download File 5</a><br>
<a href="http://domain.com/download.php?url=https://www.dropbox.com/file6.rar">Download File 6</a><br>

<a href="https://www.dropbox.com/file9.rar">Download dropbox 1</a><br>
<a href="https://www.dropbox.com/file8.rar">Download dropbox 2</a><br>

<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a><br>
<a href="https://domain.com">HomePage</a><br>
```

I managed to select the links that need to be replaced by jQuery

> $("a[href*='download.php?url=']")

But I need help to remove this part only `http://domain.com/download.php?url=`

code in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Toth/dB6nW/

the result I need like this

http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Toth/dB6nW/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
$('a[href*="download.php?url="]').attr('href', function () {
    return $(this).attr('href').split('=')[1];
});
```

Notice the implicit iteration, `each()` is not needed.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n45UV/).

Answer (score 1):

It's fix your problem:

```
$("a[href*='download.php?url=']").each(function(){
    var t = $(this);
    var url = t.attr('href').replace('http://domain.com/download.php?url=', '');
    t.attr('href', url);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dB6nW/5/

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
$(function () {
$("a[href*='download.php?url=']").each(function(i,v){
var oldUrl = $(this).attr('href');
var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("http://domain.com/download.php?url=","");
$(this).attr('href', newUrl);
});
});
```

Comment: `.replace()` expect 1st argument to be Regexp, not string (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: you could just try `oldUrl.replace(/http.*url=/, '');`

Comment: @hindmost [Nope...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: W3 schools discords on you: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter

Answer (score 0):

```
var stringToRemove = 'http://domain.com/download.php?url=';
$('a').each(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    var newLink = link.replace(stringToRemove, '');
    console.log(newLink);
});
```

A little simplified script.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this:

```
var links = $("a[href*='download.php?url=']");

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
var current = links.eq(i);    
      var href = current.attr("href");
   var newHref = href.substr(href.indexOf("="), href.length);    
   current.attr("href", newHref);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dB6nW/7/